# Error message is not displayed when when validating a user using spring framework

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, spring-security-oauth2

So I am trying to authenticate a user using a `POST` login `API` but the issue is when the user does not exist (meaning username (unique) not in the database) the thrown error message is not displayed on the client side (`POSTMAN`). I tried debugging and the error is thrown but not displayed all I see is `Status: 401 Unauthorized` from `POSTMAN`

But when the user exists but the password doesn't match, it displays the correct thrown error message. NOTE: I am using spring's OAuth 2.0 Resource Server JWT

Controller method

```
@PostMapping(path = "/login", consumes = "application/json")
    public ResponseEntity<?> login(@Valid @RequestBody UserDTO userDTO) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        LOGGER.info("Authenticating {}", userDTO.getUsername());
        
        userDTOService.confirmUser(userDTO); // Where the issue occurs
        
        Authentication authentication = authenticationManager
                .authenticate(new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(userDTO.getUsername(), userDTO.getPassword()));

        return ResponseEntity.ok()
                .header(
                        HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION,
                        tokenService.generateToken(authentication)
                )
                .build();
    }
```

Service method (confirm user method)

```
public void confirmUser(UserDTO userDTO) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        /*
        * Check if username exist in the database
        * Check if the password provided equals password in database
        * */
        String username = userDTO.getUsername();
        String password = userDTO.getPassword();
        Optional<User> user = userRepository.findUserByUserName(username);
        
        // This error is not displayed
        if (user.isEmpty()) {
            LOGGER.error("User {} does not exist", username);
            throw new UsernameNotFoundException(username + " does not exist");
        }


        boolean checkingCredentials = user
                .stream()
                .anyMatch(
                        param ->
                                param.getUsername().equals(username)
                                        &&
                                        passwordEncoder.matches(password, param.getPassword())
                );

        if (!checkingCredentials) {
            LOGGER.error("Bad user credentials");
            throw new RuntimeException("Please check username or password");
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason I was getting a 401 instead of the correct error message is because my approach was wrong. I had 2 solutions to this but I am not sure if the 2nd is the industry standard.

The first approach:

1. Pass the user credentials to a `UsernamePasswordToken` to generate a token.
2. Then I the token into the authentication manager to be authenticated
3. Surround the auth manager in a try catch block to return an exception. The thrown error message will be of your chosen.

The second approach:

1. I want to check if user exists in the database or else throw Not found exception
2. If step 1 passed then I want to check the user password trying to log in and the hashed password in the database. If they do not match, I want to throw an invalid password exception
3. If no error is thrown, then I want to pass the users name, password and authorities into `UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken()`.